# Defining this function returns absolutely nothing back:

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong with this code, it's not returning anything back at all and is just blank.

```py
def square(x):
    return x*x

square(3.0)

runfile('C:/Users/taran/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/taran/.spyder-py3'):
```

Comment: Are you expecting your program to print something? Try using `print`.

Comment: You called `square(3.0)` but didn't save the return value or print it.

Comment: Yes, as the above commenters have pointed out, it looks like you are only calling square(3.0), which does not print the result. Try modifying it to `print(square(3.0))`. You can also run this as `./temp.py` from a terminal.

Comment: `print(square(3.0))`

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

```
def square(x):
    print(x*x)

square(3.0)
```

Method 2:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

print(square(3.0))
```

Method 3:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

sq = square(3.0)
print(sq)
```